# Build a simple form to submit a name. Then go to another page which says Hello, name. in flask

Tags: python, flask

so I get this error

"Could not build URL for endpoint 'success'. Did you forget to specify values ['name']?"
what is do be done to rectify this

This is the main snippet if the server.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/success/<name>') 
def success(name): 
   return 'welcome %s' % name 
@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def login(): 
   if request.method == 'POST': 
      user = request.form['nm'] 
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user)) 
   else: 
      user = request.args.get('nm') 
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user)) 
return render_template('login.html') 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   app.run(debug = True)
```

login.html that contains a simple form with the

```
    <html> 
   <body>       
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/login" method = "post"> 
         <p>Enter Name:</p> 
         <p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p> 
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p> 
      </form>       
   </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/login` route is not mapped to any handler.

Rather `login()` is attached to `/` route which when accessed (GET request) doesn't contain `nm`  in `request.args` and therefore your `user` variable is set to `None`.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/success/<name>') 
def success(name): 
   return 'welcome %s' % name 


@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def login(): 
   if request.method == 'POST': 
      user = request.form['nm'] 
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user)) 
   else: 
      user = request.args.get('nm') 
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user)) 


@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Assuming template is available
    return render_template('login.html')
 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   app.run(debug = True)
```